# Animate transition of view controllers from one to another without navigation controller stack 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How i can Animate transition of view controllers from one to another without navigation controller stack. View Controller is managed only by UIToolbar because it has only play, rewind, stop, info and option buttons. My code is given below right now i have is 23 view controllers which are loading one after the other but during transition UIToolbar is also flipping along with the view controllers which is wrong.

```
-(void)playAction:(id)sender
{
[audioPlayer play];
[self performSelector:@selector(displayviewsAction:) withObject:nil afterDelay:11.0];
}

- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{ 
First *firstController = [[First alloc] init];
firstController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation]; 
[transitionAnimation setDuration:1];  
[transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionFade];   
[transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction     functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];  
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionFade];
[self.view addSubview:firstController.view];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[firstController release];  
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:23 target:self selector:@selector(Second) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];    
}

-(void)Second
{
Second *secondController = [[Second alloc] init];
secondController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];
[transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
[transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionFade];
[transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionFade];
[self.view addSubview:secondController.view];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[secondController release];
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:27 target:self selector:@selector(Third) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)Third {
Third *thirdController = [[Third alloc] init];
thirdController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];
[transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
[transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionFade];
[transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionFade];   
[self.view addSubview:thirdController.view];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[thirdController release];
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:23 target:self selector:@selector(Fourth) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)Fourth {
Fourth *fourthController = [[Fourth alloc] init];
fourthController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];
[transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
[transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionReveal];
[transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionReveal];
[self.view addSubview:fourthController.view];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[fourthController release];
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:25 target:self selector:@selector(Fifth) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

I am still looking for solution. Will appreciate help.

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. UIViews are added as subviews, not UIViewControllers. In your example above, you autorelease the viewController, but add its view as a subview. This new view's controller will now be gone and likely cause errors. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: On the mainviewcontroller have a UIToolbar and Play button on it when that button is pressed it plays audio file and displays multiple uiviews one after another. So far i m able to achieve this that button plays audiofile and displays view now i want to add more views to display one after the other

Answer (score 1):

just push them all

```
NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.navigationController viewControllers]];
[controllers addObject:vc1];
[controllers addObject:vc2];
[controllers addObject:vc3];
[controllers addObject:vc4];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:controllers animated:YES];
```